# same variable with different data type in main scope

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, stack

I am currently writing a stack class， which can be used with different datatype, but here comes the problem when I want to pop different data type back to the main scope and store it in another variable, in the class function I can use template to solve this problem, but it seems like the main scope can't use template, is there a way I can declare a variable with different datatype in main?

```
int main() {
int x, y;
Stack <int> si(12); 
Stack <char> sc(10); 
Stack <string> ss(5); 
ss.Push("John");
ss.Push("Peter");
ss.Push("Mary");
y = ss.Pop();
cout << y;
cout << ss;

si.Push(9);
si.Push(8);
si.Push(7);
y = si.Pop();
cout << y;
cout << si;

sc.Push('A');
sc.Push('B');
sc.Push('D');
sc.Push('E');
y = sc.Pop();
cout << y;
cout << sc;
return 0;
```

I want to let y store any type of data, is this possible?
Here is the Pop function

```
template<class KeyType>
KeyType &Stack <KeyType>::Pop(void)
{
KeyType x;
if (IsEmpty()) 
    StackEmpty();
else 
{ 
    x = stack[top]; 
    stack[top] = -1;
    top--;
}
return x;
}
```

Comment: seems y is declared as integer, but you pop a string y = ss.Pop();

Comment: you could skip storing the output of your pop operations altogether and just print them out like `std::cout << ss.Pop()`, neatly avoiding the issue of reusing your variable...

Comment: Your `Pop` function returns a dangling reference, which is UB. You can't return a reference to a local variable like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try std::any. from c++17

Answer (score 0):

In the "main scope" you know the type because you are declaring the `Stack<type>`, however you can use `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way I can declare a variable with different datatype in main?

You can use the [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) data structures from C++17 to enable a variable to have multiple data types.

If your using any one of these two data structures, there are two functions which is to be used in order to get the data stored within. For `std::any`, its `std::any_cast<>()` and for `std::variant`, its simply `std::get<>()`.

**Using `std::any`**

```cpp
int main() {
    std::any x, y;
    Stack <int> si(12);
    Stack <char> sc(10);
    Stack <string> ss(5);
    ss.Push("John");
    ss.Push("Peter");
    ss.Push("Mary");
    y = ss.Pop();
    cout << std::any_cast<std::string>(y);
    cout << ss;

    si.Push(9);
    si.Push(8);
    si.Push(7);
    y = si.Pop();
    cout << std::any_cast<int>(y);
    cout << si;

    sc.Push('A');
    sc.Push('B');
    sc.Push('D');
    sc.Push('E');
    y = sc.Pop();
    cout << std::any_cast<char>(y);
    cout << sc;
    return 0;
}
```

**Using `std::variant`**

```cpp
int main() {
    std::variant<int, char, std::string> x, y;
    Stack <int> si(12);
    Stack <char> sc(10);
    Stack <string> ss(5);
    ss.Push("John");
    ss.Push("Peter");
    ss.Push("Mary");
    y = ss.Pop();
    cout << std::get<std::string>(y);
    cout << ss;

    si.Push(9);
    si.Push(8);
    si.Push(7);
    y = si.Pop();
    cout << std::get<int>(y);
    cout << si;

    sc.Push('A');
    sc.Push('B');
    sc.Push('D');
    sc.Push('E');
    y = sc.Pop();
    cout << std::get<char>(y);
    cout << sc;
    return 0;
}
```